# Cell content disappears on scrolling and clicking on cell

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8

On scrolling cell contents disappears. I am using  this code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleCell";

    SimpleCell *cell = (SimpleCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.name.text=@"hello";
    return cell;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this   ` if (cell == nil) { cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];  }`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nib for your custom `UITableViewCell` then you don't need to initialize it from the nib in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

Do the following

In your `viewDidLoad:` method (if you are using ViewController) or `awakeFromNib:` method (if you are using UIView) register your custom cell.

```
[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SimpleCell"] bundle:[NSBundle mainBindle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SimpleCell"];
```

Now in your delegate method, do the following

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleCell";
    SimpleCell *cell = (SimpleCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    cell.name.text=@"hello";
    return cell;
}
```